# Leaving validation on empty email address with jquery regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery regex to validate an email address, but i don't want this validation to be applied on empty field, please tell me how can i solve it

```
(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i)
```

Comment: if( $('email').val() != '' ) or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if($.trim($('textEmail').val()).length == 0){
    //show some error
}
else{
    //do your regex here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your good answer, but actually its a secondary email field, and if user leave it blank than its ok and nothing needs to validate nor to show any error message, but if he enters some thing i.e invalid email address than it should check validations.
Thank you for your response

Answer (score 2):

I just found this regex, and it doesn't validate any empty field for email address but checks if email entered in invalid, this worked for me

`/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try as

```
if($("#textEmail").val() == "" || $("#textEmail").val() == undefined)
{
  alert("Please enter email");
}
else
{
   //Regex Validation
   //Other call as want
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your good answer, but actually its a secondary email field, and if user leave it blank than its ok and nothing needs to validate nor to show any error message, but if he enters some thing i.e invalid email address than it should check validations.
Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

It's simple --

```
if($('#textEmail').val().trim() != ""){
  //validate your Email
}
```